# why my rule in udev/rules.d does not set the mode and group

Tags: udev

```
jardag@precise-GiB:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 15ba:002a Olimex Ltd. ARM-USB-TINY-H JTAG interface
jardag@precise-GiB:~$ cd /dev/bus/usb
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 0 Apr  4 21:13 001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 5 Apr  4 21:13 006

jardag@precise-GiB:/dev/bus/usb/001$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/40*
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x15ba", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x002a", MODE="0660", GROUP="lp"
```

Why the mode and group of the 006 did not change ?

Answer (score 1):

Three yrs later but still...

You are trying to use a hot-swap capable NTFS-drive (USB) with specific `rwx` privilege. For that I believe, you should set a udev rule so that it actually *mounts* yr volume with said permissions.

The rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x15ba",ATTRS{idProduct}=="0x002a",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/arm_usbtiny", RUN+="/bin/mount -o relatime,utf8,gid=7,umask=0002 /dev/%k /media/arm_usbtiny"
```

Here yr drive gets mounted at `/media/arm_usbtiny`. Change that to whatever you like. 
Determine what numeric gid goes for your `lp` group. On my Ubuntu 14.04 boxes, it is `7`by default. It may be different on a different release. To check that in terminal (CTRL-ALT+T):

```
$ awk -F\: '/lp/ {print "Group " $1 " has gid=" $3}' /etc/group
```

In the udev rule, `umask=0002` is equivalent to `MODE=0664`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your rule is overridden by a late rule.

```
~$ /lib/udev/rules.d/40-flashrom.rules

# Olimex ARM-USB-TINY-H
# http://olimex.com/dev/arm-usb-tiny-h.html
ATTRS{idVendor}=="15ba", ATTRS{idProduct}=="002a", MODE="664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Try rename your rule to start with number higher then `90-*`